# Conversion of JSON String to Object always returns nil

Tags: swift

I'm fairly new to this. Anyway, here we go:

I have JSON data that comes from an API. For the sake of this question, I have simplified it greatly. You can run the following code in a Playground.

```
import UIKit

struct Book: Codable {
    let image: String
}

// this comes from my API
let jsonString = "{ \"image\" = \"someURL\" }"
print(jsonString)   // { "image" = "someURL" }

// convert String to Data
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)

// decode data (in my project, I catch the error, of course)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let decodingResult = try? decoder.decode(Book.self, from: jsonData!)
print(decodingResult)         // nil
```

As you can see, I'm trying to decode my JSON-String into an Object (my Struct), but the Decoder always returns `nil`.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: `try?`: It means if it fails, it's okay. I don't want to use (for reading for instance) a possible error that could be thrown. Use a `do`/`catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `jsonString` isn't a proper JSON. Change it to `"{ \"image\": \"someURL\" }"`, and it should work. For more information on JSON syntax, check [this manual](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).